# Grails: calculation of date intervals within 'Where' closure

Tags: date, grails, grails-orm, operations

i have the following table 'party' with start date und duration attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE `party` (
  `idparty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `startDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idparty`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The 'durartion' represents the duration in minutes.

i can query with following selects (MySQL):

```
SELECT * FROM test.party  where startDate + interval duration minute > curdate();
```

if i wish to select so called planned entries in future.

I can query to select the entries from past:

```
SELECT * FROM test.party  where startDate + interval duration minute < curdate();
```

Now i wish process such queries with GRAILS Framework using the  'Where' closure. I have the domain class Party with startDate as Date and duration as Integer.

I tried to use within Party.where {} closure the TimeCategory, plain additions , old shool java.util.Date to defie such queries without success:

either the where parts will be ignored or the exceptions will be thrown.

I [found](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2434), that open BUG by Hibernate framework exists..

The question is, if it is generally possilbe, such operations with GRAILS to do?

Comment: add a redundant `endDate` field, and run the plain queries like `between`

Comment: have you tried `executeQuery`?

Comment: Where queries, from my experience, are not worth using. They look nice in theory, but have a lot of issues. I'd go with a Criteria and see if that works.